# Rails 4 - simple form: how do I populate a form field based on the link used to access the form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden-field

I have models in my Rails 4 app for Projects and Interests. The associations are:

Project

```
has_many :interests
```

Interest

```
belongs_to :project
belongs to: user
```

The purpose of the interest form is for users to register interest in a project.

In my projects show view, I have two links to register interest. Users can express interest in a project either as a participant or as an observer.

In my interest form, I have two boolean fields called :participant and :observer.

I'm trying to figure out how to populate the relevant boolean attribute with 'true', depending on which link the user clicks to get to the form. If they click 'participate in this project', then the participant attribute in the interest table should be set to true.

In my interest form, I have:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, @current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, @project.id %>

<%= f.input :observe, as: :radio_buttons, :label => "Do you want to monitor this project?" %>
<%= f.input :participate, as: :radio_buttons, :label => "Do you want to participate in this project?" %>
```

Is there a way that I can auto-complete the observe and participate booleans in this form, based on which link the user follows to access this form, from the projects show?

Routes for interests (it's actually called 'eoi' in my app:

```
rake routes | grep eoi
                        eois GET       /eois(.:format)                                             eois#index
                             POST      /eois(.:format)                                             eois#create
                     new_eoi GET       /eois/new(.:format)                                         eois#new
                    edit_eoi GET       /eois/:id/edit(.:format)                                    eois#edit
                         eoi GET       /eois/:id(.:format)                                         eois#show
                             PATCH     /eois/:id(.:format)                                         eois#update
                             PUT       /eois/:id(.:format)                                         eois#update
                             DELETE    /eois/:id(.:format)                                         eois#destroy
```

In the projects show view, I have these links to register interest to participate or monitor a project:

```
<%= link_to 'Participate', new_eoi_path(@eoi) %>
<%= link_to 'Monitor', new_eoi_path(@eoi) %>
```

Comment: Can you post the code in projects/show.html.erb?

Comment: @ArunKumar - I have added the routes and links above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your view

```
<%= link_to 'Participate', new_task_path(@eoi, participate: true) %>

<%= link_to 'Monitor', new_task_path(@eoi, observe: true) %>
```

And in your controller,

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
  @participate = params[:participate] # will be nil if observe link was clicked
  @observe = params[:observe]
end
```

And finally in the forms, set `checked` to the value based on `@observe` or `@participate`

```
<%= f.input :observe, checked: @observe, as: :radio_buttons, :label => "Do you want to monitor this project?" %>
<%= f.input :participate, checked: @participate, as: :radio_buttons, :label => "Do you want to participate in this project?" %>
```

**EXTRA**

If the user clicks on the `observe` link, you would want to check `observe` and also`uncheck` `participate`. To do so, replace your `new` action with

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
  @participate = params[:participate] || false
  @observe = params[:observe] || false
end
```

This way, if the user clicks on the `observe` link, the value of `yes` will be set for `observe` and `no` will set for `participate`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's really helpful.

Comment: @Mel, see the edit. It improves UX cause we pre-populate both the fields based on the user's wish.

Comment: Thanks so much Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in whether it is observer or participate in the query string of the form.

Change the route helper that goes to this form to

```
new_eoi_path(observe: true)
```

or

```
new_eoi_path(participate: true)
```

And then change your inputs in the new view to

```
<%= f.input :observe, checked: params[:observe],as: :radio_buttons, :label => "Do you want to monitor this project?" %>
<%= f.input :participate, checked: params[:participate], as: :radio_buttons, :label => "Do you want to participate in this project?" %>
```

Edit

How about using this for the inputs?

```
<%= f.radio_button :observe, true, :checked => params[:observe] %>
<%= f.radio_button :participate, true, :checked => params[:participate] %>
```

Comment: thanks very much for the suggestion. I tried this, but when I render the form, neither radio button is selected.

Comment: Did you do "new_eoi_path(observe: true)" or "new_eoi_path(@eoi, observe: true)"? You probably want the first one. It does not make sense to pass an object into your new since you will be creating that object.

Comment: <%= link_to 'Participate', new_eoi_path(participate: true) %>

Comment: I tried the other way too - but I can't get that to work either

Comment: That didn't work, but <%= f.hidden_field :participate, :value => true, :checked => params[:participate] %> does work - but then I can't use the same form for both links. I only want participate to be true if the user follows the participate link to get to the form. If I don't use a form field for participate (and just try and write the link path the way you showed me, the saved value of participate is nil (instead of true).

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is with your code. At this point, the only way I could help you is if you upload your project to GitHub and then I can pull it down and try to get it working myself.

Comment: Thanks so much for the steer. I'll keep going and try to see what I've done wrong. The repo is private and I don't have permission to share. Thanks so much just the same.